# HandbrakeCLI command lines

Tags: audio, video, command-line, handbrake, handbrakecli

I'm trying to convert DVD iso files to mp4 using HandbrakeCLI. I use the following line in a batch file:

```
D:\HandBrakeCLI.exe -i "D:\input.iso" -o "D:\output.mp4" --no-markers --width "720" --height "480" --preset "HQ 480p30 Surround" --encoder "mpeg2" --audio-lang-list "eng"
```

When I do this, I must then extract the audio from the file, using the following line:

```
D:\eac3to\eac3to.exe "D:\output.mp4" "D:\output.wavs" -down16
```

However, when I attempt to extract the audio, I get the error message

> The format of the source file could not be detected.

Is there anything wrong with my former line of code that's causing the mp4 to get screwed up?

Minor side question: I'm also trying to get handbrake to remove subtitles and also only keep English audio, do you know what code could be used for that? I started a bit there with the `--audio-lang-list` "eng" but I'm now sure what to do from there.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a valid audio format. `.wavs` is not valid. You have to use an available audio codec to output to the below for `--aencoder`. The default output audio for MP4 is `.aac`

> av_aac
>
> copy:aac
>
> ac3
>
> copy:ac3
>
> eac3
>
> copy:eac3
>
> copy:truehd
>
> copy:dts
>
> copy:dtshd
>
> mp3
>
> copy:mp3
>
> vorbis
>
> flac16
>
> flac24
>
> copy:flac
>
> opus
>
> copy

Defaults for audio

> av_mp4 = av_aac
>
> av_mkv = mp3

You need to pass `none` for no subtitles

```
-s none
```

And define only `eng` track like you were doing

```
--audio-lang-list eng
```

Check out the Handbrake CLI Documentation for the command line code:

https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/cli/cli-guide.html

You can also try using a different program once you extract the audio. A program like XMediaRecode. It can also remux audio and video and convert other audio formats to `wav`

https://www.videohelp.com/software/XMedia-Recode

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the answer!

Comment: @RealFL Great, glad to help.. If this answered your question feel free to mark this as the accepted answer :)